# Async behaviour when rendering data to headers

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get **token** from localstorage in my `react-native` application.
whenever I run the code below, the token is passed successfully.

```js
const setHeaders = () => {
    const header = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MWNjZjk2MmYxYjkxZDEzMDQ3NmU3NWEiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSnV3b25fSmF2YSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZmFkZXlpYmkyNkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDEzODA4OTAsImV4cCI6MTY0MTk4NTY5MH0.R_8Yum7s3DuQ7yulSYsNRWRkWGuCTxB_jq39hVn9iQA"
      }
    }
    return header
  }
```

but the moment I add async to get the code from `AsyncStorage`, it seems not to work but the token is displayed in the console if i want to display it. i'm really confused, somebody should help me out. this is the async code below

```js
const setHeaders = async() => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log('setToken', token) // it sends token to the console but not to the header
    const header = {
      headers: {
        // Authorization: token
        Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MWNjZjk2MmYxYjkxZDEzMDQ3NmU3NWEiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSnV3b25fSmF2YSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZmFkZXlpYmkyNkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDEzODA4OTAsImV4cCI6MTY0MTk4NTY5MH0.R_8Yum7s3DuQ7yulSYsNRWRkWGuCTxB_jq39hVn9iQA"
      }
    }
    return header
  }
```

Kindly help me please!

Comment: maybe try adding **"Bearer " + token**

Comment: "Bearer" is added from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Kindly send token without saving into variable. I hope it will work.

```js
const setHeaders = async() => {
    
    const header = {
      headers: {
         Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      }
    }
    return header
  }
```

Comment: its still throwing unauthorized error

Comment: kindly tell me token is gone or not with headers ?

Comment: Zeeshan Akram, I don't seems to get your question

Comment: i just ask you when you call api token is gone with header or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the token where you're calling `setHeaders` and pass it as a parameter, like:

```js
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    setHeaders(token);
```

then do it like this:

```js
const setHeaders = (token) => {
    
    const header = {
      headers: {
         Authorization: token;
      }
    }
    return header
 }
```

Also, make sure `token` is a string.
Hope this works for you!